# Formatting Strings in JavaScript to use as HTML "MAILTO" links

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

Here are some strings that I'm using to ultimately form a HTML `mailto` link.  I'm doing this in javascript.  If I output the `mailtoString` to an `alert()` I get the link looks just fine.  However, when I put it into the `location.href` the string is cut short at the "&" character.  How do I tell the `location.href` that the "&" is not the end of the `mailto` link?

```
    var subject = escape('subject');
    var body = escape('body');
    var reportUrl = document.URL + "/GetUpdatedTableResults?beginDate=" + beginDate + "&endDate=" + endDate + "&fileId=" + DocId + '&languageCode=' + LangCode + '&documentResultType=' + result + '&result=' + ReportedIssue;
    var excelUrl = document.URL + 'CurReport/GetCSVReport?beginDate=' + beginDate + '&endDate=' + endDate + '&fileId=' + DocId + '&languageCode=' + LangCode + '&documentResultType=' + result + '&result=' + ReportedIssue;
    var mailtoString = 'mailto:?subject=' + subject + '&body=' + body + '%0A%0AWeb:%0A' + reportUrl + '%0A%0AExcel:%0A' + excelUrl;        
    location.href = mailtoString;
```

After running the code above I get the following output.

```
http://localhost:5050/CurReport/GetUpdatedTableResults?beginDate=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Because immediately after `mailto:` should be the email address. `?` is a valid email characters but `&` is not. Anyway, the `&` should be escaped to `&amp;`.

Comment: Yes, the email address should come after the `mailto:` but I just want outlook (or default) to open a new email with the "to" field blank.

Comment: Did you encode the ampersand? Different email programs have their own restrictions on what fields you can preset. I would your version of Outlook won't allow the body to be preset.